# How to find information about buildings using specific addresses?

Tags: data-request, geospatial, api, openfda

As indicated in the question, I am looking for all kind of information about buildings in Switzerland, preferably using an API. This could include information like whether a restaurant or a bank is located in this building or (if possible) information about when it was built.

Two possible sources I have in mind are using the Google Places API or the OSM API. However,concerning the Google API, I am a little bit concerned that the daily requests are limited. But since I don't have much experience in this area, I would very much appreciate to benefit from your experience.

Comment: Worldwide? Please [edit] your question.

Comment: @ Jan Doggen Thanks for your comment. It would also be interesting to look at geographic differences but I am mostly interested in information for Switzerland.

Comment: I would at least try mass downloading Swiss information from OSM and looking at the quality. For bulk data like this, I wouldn't recommend using the API.